# Cannot Recognize the Syntax of this code(Which is Class, and which is Method)?

Tags: java, oop, object, junit

I have a problem with a code, which is I found an object linked to a class and this class calls a method and the method is trying to call another method? I know there is no nested method in Java.

But here is a sample of the code.

I tried to make the code as a class, class and a method but didn't work.

In the first file, we created an object of another class in another file.

```
    private SnackMachine snackMachine;
```

The name of the class is "SnackMachine and snackMachine is the object.

in the use of the code.

```
assertThat(snackMachine.chewingGums().quantity()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_QUANTITY);
```

as we see here object is calling a method, but after the method what is that?
and how can I replicate that?

I thought It's class inherited from another class and that has a method.
also I thought because it's we used the final keyword or static so we could call it with creating an object.

I assume DEFUALT_QUANTITY is a number, so quantity will have to return a number, that means it is a method.

I assume that First return an object and the second calls that object and invoke its the method.

Comment: It is the method making the second call, but what the method returns that is making the second method call. (A.B().C())

Comment: I don't know, because I don't have that code, I am trying to complete a game found on github called Snacks Machine. and I am required to complete the code.

Q: how do I write a code do same calls as you said?

Comment: Here is the link of the code

Comment: [link](http://github.com/vegegoku/induction-task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the first method returns another object and so you can chain another call. The returned value is taken from the last call.

For example this (note the lack of semi-colons)

```
package com.github.francipvb.holamundo;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder()
            // The append method returns the builder itself...
            .append("str")
            .append("another str")
            .toString(); // this is the last call.
        System.out.println(sb); // sb is a string
    }
}
```

Comment: [code] (@Test
    void new_snack_machine_should_have_three_types_of_snacks() {
        assertThat(snackMachine.chewingGums().quantity()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_QUANTITY);
        assertThat(snackMachine.chips().quantity()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_QUANTITY);
        assertThat(snackMachine.chocolates().quantity()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_QUANTITY);
    })

Comment: Just return the object you want to chain calls to. In the string builder example, these method return the builder itself so you can chain calls to it.